# POST data empty if no value is set (Problems with typo3)

Tags: php, post, typo3

it seems like i have a strange server setting active which makes my post fields getting deleted if they dont have any value. So we are talking about server configuration!

i have a very simple form to test it:

PLEASE ... dont search for bugs in this little form since it is only there to show you that the server IS ignoring empty params. The typo3 part is following at the end of the question ... so read all the question before you rate it as not usefull.

```
<?php
    echo '<h2>GET</h2>';
    print_r($_GET);
    echo '<h2>POST</h2>';
    print_r($_POST);
    echo '<h2>REQUEST</h2>';
    var_dump($_REQUEST);
    echo '<h2>FILE_GET_CONTENTS</h2>';
    var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));
?>

<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="test" /> <input type="submit" name="button" value="submit">
</form>
```

If i dont fill the input field i get the following output:

```
GET
Array ( )
POST
Array ( [button] => submit )
REQUEST
array(1) { ["button"]=> string(6) "submit" }
FILE_GET_CONTENTS
string(19) "test=&button=submit"
```

if i fill any value (like 'test') into the input field i get the following output:

```
GET
Array ( )
POST
Array ( [test] => test [button] => submit )
REQUEST
array(2) { ["test"]=> string(4) "test" ["button"]=> string(6) "submit" }
FILE_GET_CONTENTS
string(23) "test=test&button=submit"
```

So why is my field "test" only present, if there is any value given to it?

The main reason for this question is, that typo3 uses empty fields to validate, which action is to be done in all of its forms like changing configuration settings or testing the setup. All these function don't work, since the flags, given by the forms, are not present.

This is, what a typo3 action form is looking like:

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="install[controller]" value="tool">
  <input type="hidden" name="install[action]" value="testSetup">
  <input type="hidden" name="install[token]" value="ldfjlskdflsdkjflsdkjf">
  <input type="hidden" name="install[context]" value="backend">

  <h4>Scaling images</h4>

  <fieldset class="t3-install-form-submit">
      <ol>
          <li>
              <button class="btn " type="submit" name="install[set][testScalingImages]">
                  Test scaling images
              </button>
          </li>
      </ol>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

If i add a value="1" to the submit button everything works since my server don't deletes the param then ... but i don't want to change all typo3 forms in all typo3 installs. So it have to be any server configuration issue.

ive read a lot about working on code site to get a more raw variant of the post data, but since i would have to change this in a lot of typo3 installations a server-wide solution would be much better.

Comment: replace `<input name="test">` with `<input type="text" name="test">`

Comment: BTW I can't see any TYPO3 part here

Comment: than u did not read my question fully ... the provided form is just to show u that the server is ignoring empty params ....

Comment: Just a suggestion: does your "System Environment" tab from Install Tool show any errors? Especially about `register_globals` turned on (must be off).

Comment: No sorry, there are no errors except of "Empty systemLocale setting" ($GLOBALS[TYPO3_CONF_VARS][SYS][systemLocale] is not set. This is fine as long as no UTF-8 file system is used) and "No PHP opcode cache loaded". Both shoulnd be a problem in this context.

Answer (score 3):

You should change your form to :

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="test" /> <input type="submit" name="button" value="submit">
</form>
```

Without any type setted, the server can't understand what you're expecting to get with this input.

Comment: we are NOT talking about my simple test form ... that was only to show u, that the server IS ignoring empty params ... its a server question ... not html

Comment: If you dont set a type to your input it's NORMAL that the server ignore them while empty, as stated in my answer

Comment: well its absolutly the same problem, if i add type="text" to the input field ... and even if it would work it would not explain, why typo3 have the problem which ive explained only on this server.